# Sending path variables to REST API

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I had a controller that accepted params

```
@GetMapping(value = "/messages/getReceivedMessage")
public
HttpEntity<ReceivedMessageDTO> getReceivedMessage(
        @ApiParam(value = "The message ID", required = true) @RequestParam Long id
)
```

and I gets the data using an AngularJS in this way

```
$http({
        url: '/messages/getReceivedMessage',
        method: "GET",
        params: {
            id: messageId
        }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.message = response.data;

            if(response.data.date_of_read === null) {
                setDateOfRead();
            }
        })
        .catch(function () {
            console.log('failed');
        });
```

but now I have decided to change the REST API address and it will accept path variables

```
@GetMapping(value = "/received/{id}")
public
HttpEntity<ReceivedMessageDTO> getReceivedMessage(
        @ApiParam(value = "The message ID", required = true) @PathVariable Long id
)
```

How I can send path variables to controller?

Comment: So is the question adding path variables in urls angularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need but all you have to do is call your endpoint using url like  `"/received/" + someId`

Or in angular like

```
$http.get('/received/' + someId)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pass message id along with URL

```
http({ url: '/received/' + messageId, method: "GET"}) .then(function (response) { $scope.message = response.data; if(response.data.date_of_read === null) { setDateOfRead(); } }) .catch(function () { console.log('failed'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
$http({
        url: '/messages/getReceivedMessage',
        method: "GET",
        params: {
            id: messageId
        }
    })
```

to

```
$http({
        url: '/messages/'+messageId,
        method: "GET"
      })
```

Since, your parameter value became part of path.